# Is there a keyboard shortcut to close a window in Windows?

Tags: windows-8

I have always wondered if there was and this would improve my productivity manifold times.

Comment: http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Windows_8.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> has been the Close Window shortcut since Windows 3.1

Comment: Unfortunately pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del twice to quickly close multiple windows has been taken out since Windows ME :(