# Windows 3.1 WORKING keyboard shortcut to close active window

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

This doesn't work:

[Is there a keyboard shortcut to close a window in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/935494/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-close-a-window-in-windows)

I have Windows 3.1 on old pc, few windows open. I cannot close using Alt+F4 as suggested here, because the whole windows session wants to close. Having no muse, how can I close active window without exiting windows?

Alt + Tabs flicks through open windows, but regardless which one is active Alt+F4 always wants to close windows.

[image]

Comment: if you do alt-space do you get a menu? that worked in win9x and even up till today, and might have worked in win 3.1? another thing to try is alt-f to bring up the file menu and exit will be there.

Comment: In a sub-Window, see the top left icon in the toolbar, Click on that and select Close. That will close the sub-Window without exiting Windows. This is working on my Windows 3.1 machine here.

Comment: Yes but only for main window, even if I'm already in Accessories as an active windows

Comment: Great John, but how do I click without mouse as described?

Comment: Ctrl-F4 closes the active window.  Also consider using a Mouse. Windows (from Windows 3 forward) works vastly better with a mouse

Comment: Works, put it as an answer pease, John.

Comment: Thanks.  I have done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 3.1, to close a sub-Window without exiting Windows itself, be in the sub-Window (that window active), and use Ctrl-F4 to close the window. This works without exiting Windows.